# Pytest-cov with Moto in list_stacks() from Boto3

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, boto3, moto, pytest-cov

I'm trying to create a test with pytest and moto  that check if the `StackStatus` from the dictionary returned from the function `list_stacks()` (https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudformation.html#CloudFormation.Client.list_stacks) is `DELETE_COMPLETE`.

I create a pytest.fixture for the client connection:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def cf(aws_credentials):
    with mock_cloudformation():
        yield boto3.client('cloudformation')
```

And I created a dummie template:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def template_body_data():
    'The Cloud Formation template'
    template_data = {
        'Resources': {'MyS3Bucket': {'Type': 'AWS::S3::Bucket', 'Properties': {}}}
    }
    return template_data
```

And in my test function I create the stack and after I deleted:

```
@mock_cloudformation
def test_deleted_stack(cf, template_body_data):
    params = {'StackName': 'teste', 'TemplateBody': yaml.dump(template_body_data)}
    cf.create_stack(**params)
    cf.delete_stack(StackName='teste')
    assert check_stack_exists('teste') is False
```

The function that is being testes is this one:

```
def check_stack_exists(stack_name):
    cf = get_client()
    list_stack = cf.list_stacks()['StackSummaries']
    for stack in list_stack:
        if stack['StackStatus'] == 'DELETE_COMPLETE':
            continue
        if stack['StackName'] == stack_name:
            return True
    return False
```

I'm facing a issue:

It complains that my template doesn't have a BucketName:

```
___________________ test_check_stack_exists_deleted_stack ___________________

cf = <botocore.client.CloudFormation object at 0x7f59ca68f580>
template_body_data = {'Resources': {'MyS3Bucket': {'Properties': {}, 'Type': 'AWS::S3::Bucket'}}}

    @mock_cloudformation
    def test_check_stack_exists_deleted_stack(cf, template_body_data):
        'Test the stack search if the stack exists'
        params = {'StackName': 'teste', 'TemplateBody': yaml.dump(template_body_data)}
        cf.create_stack(**params)
>       cf.delete_stack(StackName='teste')

tests/test_cl_uploader.py:87: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
../../.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/cl-uploader-12nYBdPj-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py:316: in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
../../.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/cl-uploader-12nYBdPj-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py:621: in _make_api_call
    http, parsed_response = self._make_request(
../../.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/cl-uploader-12nYBdPj-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py:641: in _make_request
    return self._endpoint.make_request(operation_model, request_dict)
../../.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/cl-uploader-12nYBdPj-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py:102: in make_request
    return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
../../.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/cl-uploader-12nYBdPj-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py:136: in _send_request
    while self._needs_retry(attempts, operation_model, request_dict,
../../.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/cl-uploader-12nYBdPj-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py:253: in _needs_retry
    responses = self._event_emitter.emit(
../../.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/cl-uploader-12nYBdPj-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py:356: in emit
    return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)
../../.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/cl-uploader-12nYBdPj-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py:228: in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
../../.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/cl-uploader-12nYBdPj-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py:211: in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
../../.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/cl-uploader-12nYBdPj-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py:183: in __call__
    if self._checker(attempts, response, caught_exception):
../../.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/cl-uploader-12nYBdPj-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py:250: in __call__
    should_retry = self._should_retry(attempt_number, response,
../../.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/cl-uploader-12nYBdPj-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py:269: in _should_retry
    return self._checker(attempt_number, response, caught_exception)
../../.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/cl-uploader-12nYBdPj-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py:316: in __call__
    checker_response = checker(attempt_number, response,
../../.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/cl-uploader-12nYBdPj-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py:222: in __call__
    return self._check_caught_exception(
../../.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/cl-uploader-12nYBdPj-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py:359: in _check_caught_exception
    raise caught_exception
../../.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/cl-uploader-12nYBdPj-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py:197: in _do_get_response
    responses = self._event_emitter.emit(event_name, request=request)
../../.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/cl-uploader-12nYBdPj-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py:356: in emit
    return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)
../../.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/cl-uploader-12nYBdPj-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py:228: in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
../../.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/cl-uploader-12nYBdPj-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py:211: in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
../../.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/cl-uploader-12nYBdPj-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/moto/core/models.py:322: in __call__
    status, headers, body = response_callback(
../../.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/cl-uploader-12nYBdPj-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/moto/core/responses.py:202: in dispatch
    return cls()._dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
../../.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/cl-uploader-12nYBdPj-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/moto/core/responses.py:312: in _dispatch
    return self.call_action()
../../.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/cl-uploader-12nYBdPj-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/moto/core/responses.py:397: in call_action
    response = method()
../../.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/cl-uploader-12nYBdPj-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/moto/cloudformation/responses.py:380: in delete_stack
    self.cloudformation_backend.delete_stack(name_or_stack_id)
../../.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/cl-uploader-12nYBdPj-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/moto/cloudformation/models.py:734: in delete_stack
    self.delete_stack(stack.stack_id)
../../.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/cl-uploader-12nYBdPj-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/moto/cloudformation/models.py:726: in delete_stack
    stack.delete()
../../.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/cl-uploader-12nYBdPj-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/moto/cloudformation/models.py:363: in delete
    self.resource_map.delete()
../../.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/cl-uploader-12nYBdPj-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/moto/cloudformation/parsing.py:677: in delete
    raise last_exception
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <moto.cloudformation.parsing.ResourceMap object at 0x7f59cabd3940>

    def delete(self):
        remaining_resources = set(self.resources)
        tries = 1
        while remaining_resources and tries < 5:
            for resource in remaining_resources.copy():
                parsed_resource = self._parsed_resources.get(resource)
                try:
                    if parsed_resource and hasattr(parsed_resource, "delete"):
                        parsed_resource.delete(self._region_name)
                    else:
                        resource_name_attribute = (
                            parsed_resource.cloudformation_name_type()
                            if hasattr(parsed_resource, "cloudformation_name_type")
                            else resource_name_property_from_type(parsed_resource.type)
                        )
                        if resource_name_attribute:
                            resource_json = self._resource_json_map[
                                parsed_resource.logical_resource_id
                            ]
>                           resource_name = resource_json["Properties"][
                                resource_name_attribute
                            ]
E                           KeyError: 'BucketName'

../../.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/cl-uploader-12nYBdPj-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/moto/cloudformation/parsing.py:662: KeyError
```

But when I add one, it giver another error:

```
================================= FAILURES ==================================
___________________ test_check_stack_exists_deleted_stack ___________________

cf = <botocore.client.CloudFormation object at 0x7f7a02ca4ee0>
template_body_data = {'Resources': {'MyS3Bucket': {'Properties': {'BucketName': 'teste'}, 'Type': 'AWS::S3::Bucket'}}}

    @mock_cloudformation
    def test_check_stack_exists_deleted_stack(cf, template_body_data):
        'Test the stack search if the stack exists'
        params = {'StackName': 'teste', 'TemplateBody': yaml.dump(template_body_data)}
>       cf.create_stack(**params)

tests/test_cl_uploader.py:86: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
../../.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/cl-uploader-12nYBdPj-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py:316: in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <botocore.client.CloudFormation object at 0x7f7a02ca4ee0>
operation_name = 'CreateStack'
api_params = {'StackName': 'teste', 'TemplateBody': 'Resources:\n  MyS3Bucket:\n    Properties:\n      BucketName: teste\n    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket\n'}

    def _make_api_call(self, operation_name, api_params):
        operation_model = self._service_model.operation_model(operation_name)
        service_name = self._service_model.service_name
        history_recorder.record('API_CALL', {
            'service': service_name,
            'operation': operation_name,
            'params': api_params,
        })
        if operation_model.deprecated:
            logger.debug('Warning: %s.%s() is deprecated',
                         service_name, operation_name)
        request_context = {
            'client_region': self.meta.region_name,
            'client_config': self.meta.config,
            'has_streaming_input': operation_model.has_streaming_input,
            'auth_type': operation_model.auth_type,
        }
        request_dict = self._convert_to_request_dict(
            api_params, operation_model, context=request_context)
    
        service_id = self._service_model.service_id.hyphenize()
        handler, event_response = self.meta.events.emit_until_response(
            'before-call.{service_id}.{operation_name}'.format(
                service_id=service_id,
                operation_name=operation_name),
            model=operation_model, params=request_dict,
            request_signer=self._request_signer, context=request_context)
    
        if event_response is not None:
            http, parsed_response = event_response
        else:
            http, parsed_response = self._make_request(
                operation_model, request_dict, request_context)
    
        self.meta.events.emit(
            'after-call.{service_id}.{operation_name}'.format(
                service_id=service_id,
                operation_name=operation_name),
            http_response=http, parsed=parsed_response,
            model=operation_model, context=request_context
        )
    
        if http.status_code >= 300:
            error_code = parsed_response.get("Error", {}).get("Code")
            error_class = self.exceptions.from_code(error_code)
>           raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
E           botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (Unknown) when calling the CreateStack operation: Unknown

../../.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/cl-uploader-12nYBdPj-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/botocore/client.py:635: ClientError
```

Answer (score 0):

Very late answer, but since you specified an S3 bucket type in the template, the cloudformation client will likely try making calls to S3 to check if the bucket resource exists. So we would also need to mock those s3 calls. You need to put a `@mock_s3` annotation in that test method:

```
@mock_s3
@mock_cloudformation
def test_deleted_stack(cf, template_body_data):
    params = {'StackName': 'teste', 'TemplateBody': yaml.dump(template_body_data)}
    cf.create_stack(**params)
    cf.delete_stack(StackName='teste')
    assert check_stack_exists('teste') is False
```